# Scroll not working on iframe

Tags: css, iframe, scroll, scrollbar

I'm having a hard time configuring the scroll on an iframe.

I have this form, where the height is dynamic dependening on wether the expandable tabs are opened or not. This form is inside an iframe.

The issue is that when the cursor is above the iframe, the mouse scroll doesn't work.

In other words: If the cursor is on the white area, the mouse scroll won't work. If the cursor is on the blue area, the mouse scroll will work just fine.

I leave you a link of the form so you can understand it better: http://catari.pt/pt/store2.html

I've already changed the scrolling="no" to scrolling="yes", changed the height to absolute and relative sizes, and nothing seems to be solving it.. I also changed the overflow-x and y values and still nothing. Is there any way to solve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is handle the MouseWheel event as stated here 
[MouseWheel Event](https://www.sitepoint.com/html5-javascript-mouse-wheel/). and in the function you can do something like

```
function MouseWheelHandler(e) {

     // cross-browser wheel delta
     var e = window.event || e; // old IE support

     // delta will give you the direct
     var delta = Math.max(-1, Math.min(1, (e.wheelDelta || -e.detail)));
     // you can change how much and on what increments you want to scroll
     // a simple approach can be this
     if(delta <1)
     {
          $("html, body").animate({
          scrollTop: $(document).height()
          }, 1000 * delta);  
     }                
     else
     {
          /scroll back up
          $("html, body").animate({
          scrollTop: 0
          }, 1000 * delta); 
      }
     return false;
}
```

This might be a overkill but this approach gives you an idea how you can do it bypassing the limitation you are facing. Make sure you follow the link and add actionListeners as stated. Cheers